# Store Keyboard shortcut in Database WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm planning to save keyboard shortcut in database. When User pressed the shortcut key, specific window should open.
A function same like Visual Studio Keyboard shortcut assign window,

[image]

Here which key combination should I store in database?

I'm listening to following method to hook the key press

```
protected override void OnKeyUp(KeyEventArgs e)
{
     // Here I'm gonna hook the keypress
}
```

If the user pressed, `CTRL + W` ( any Key combination with Control Key )

`e.KeyboardDevice.Modifiers` is `Control` and `e.Key` is `W`

If user pressed, `ALT + W` ( Any key combination with Alter Key )

`e.KeyboardDevice.Modifiers` is `Alt` and `e.Key` is `System` and `e.SystemKey` is `W`

If user pressed, `CTRL + Shift + W` its giving key combonation in two sequent OnKeyUp events

There is no common pattern.
Which combination I should Hook ? Which combination I should store in database ?

Comment: `ProcessCmdKey` is a better choice to handle short cuts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the [KeyGesture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keygesture.aspx) class. You can save and parse gestures from strings and also easily compare them in your `OnKeyUp` method like this:

```
if (e.Key == Gesture.Key && Gesture.Modifiers == Keyboard.Modifiers)
   //do stuff...
```